# Some images on Wordpress site are suddenly gone

Tags: plugins, images, html

I am not sure when this started happening as I have not been paying close attention. I've tried disabling recent plugins to no avail. Some of my images are just gone and there doesn't seem to be a pattern to which  ones, but when I copy the image location, I get a url that is something like this: http://www.pureplantessentials.comhttp//www.pureplantessentials.com/bruce_lipton1.jpg

when it should be something like this: http://www.pureplantessentials.com/bruce_lipton1.jpg

I looked in the code and it says the image url is: /bruce_lipton1.jpg

You can probably guess my site's url. What could be happening here?

Comment: Is this happening on featured images, inserted images, header images, all images? Not a lot of information to do go on here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using relative URLs in some places. That is, you are using this-- `<img src="/bruce_lipton1.jpg" />`-- instead of this-- `<img src="http://www.pureplantessentials.com/bruce_lipton1.jpg" />`.  Don't do that.

Relative URLs are very unreliable in most of WordPress. It has to do with the way that WordPress rewrites URLs. Your theme, for example, is at `wp-content/themes/theme-name/` but those theme files appear to load at any number of places such as `http://www.pureplantessentials.com/` or `http://www.pureplantessentials.com/contactus/`

Use complete URLs by means of [`bloginfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo), [any of these](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url#Related), [`get_template_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri), or [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), depending on what you need.

In fact, your image and URL conventions are not consistent. You seem to be keeping images in many different places and you sometimes use absolute URLs and sometimes relative ones. I'd recommend sticking to one consistent pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`home_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) template tag to construct your image urls, e.g.:

```
<img src="<?php echo home_url( '/bruce_lipton1.jpg' ); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and maybe that is something I should have been doing all along, but I have over 700 pages and am not going to go through each to change the image url